# Device will connect to a phone hotspot by not to my router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I note there is a similar question or possible double:

"Why can't I connect to a wifi network with my laptop, when I can with my phone?"

I assume however that the phone connection indicates that the router is OK. 
My connection, then, is a little different.

I bought a (probably relatively old) Windows 8.1 tablet (LAMINA) with Wifi difficulties. It will not connect to my (Belkin) router although a number of other devices will. When I use my (Samsung) phone as a Wifi hotspot, the tablet connects to the phone. I take this as an indication that most of the tablet´s settings are OK (?).

The most obvious advices on the net does not work, such as using config/release - config/renew and rebooting the router.  What can the differences be between the router and the hotspot?

I realize some of the answers to the question above may still be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple advanced settings on a router that your phone does not have; any one of them can be the blocker. You need to understand all the settings (or try them one-by-one) to find which one it is; here some examples:

- The router signal might be a tad too weak
- the router operates on the 5GHz band, and the tablet does not support it
- the router has a MAC address list and blocks anyone else
- the router blocks certain ports that the tablet needs
- there are some more esoteric possibilities in the router settings.